# Data verification input in loop

Tags: java

I have tried various techniques to check the values of user input in this method.  The user should only be able to enter a '1' or a '0'.  If any other input is used there should be an error message and the program exits.  Any ideas?  I got it to work for the first digit but not the second through the tenth.

```
    System.out.println("Enter a ten digit binary number.  Press 'Enter' after each digit.  Only use one or zero. :");

        binary[0] = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (index = 1; index < 10; index++)
            binary[index] = keyboard.nextInt();// fill array with 10 binary
                                                // digits from user. User
                                                // must press 'Enter' after
                                                // each digit.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (scanner.hasNext())
    {
        final String input = scanner.next();
        try
        {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(input, 2);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException error)
        {
            System.out.println(input + " is not a binary number.");
            //OR You may exit here, if you don't want to continue
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please I have to wait for 5 hours to (+1) upvote this, something I learned today with your answer. Nice One :-) Please give me that time, I loved your answer. My limit to upvote is gone for today :-(

Comment: +1, I got my voting rights back, hehe, so the first one is coming your way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code part :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputTest
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] binary = new int[10];
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            int number = scan.nextInt();
            if (number == 0 || number == 1)
            {
                binary[index] = number;
                System.out.println("Index : " + index);
            }
            else
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```